# View based NSTableView having Sluggish Scrolling

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, reuseidentifier

I am using **View based NSTableView** where I have around 30 columns and rows could be in between 200 - 1000. The problem is that the tableView is very sluggish. After doing some debugging, I figured out that adding an **identifier** to **NSTableCellView** made the scrolling super fast. But the problem arose that no data was displayed. Since all the data being displayed to the columns is using binding, so no code has been written for it. Now, I am not able to figure it out why is that happening or what is the correct way of using view based NSTableView using binding and reusing Cells. Could someone provide me some highlights on how to make the scrolling smooth for such scenarios.

Comment: What are the details of the binding to in one of the views that don't display data but that did display data before? Specifically, which object and which key path?

Comment: I have bind it to the Table Cell View's objectValue to attribute. Eg: objectValue.name etc. TableView's Content to ArrayController's arrangedObject. ArrayController is bind to viewController's array.

Comment: Is scrolling fast because no data is displayed? Are all the cells text fields?

Comment: Is scrolling fast because no data is displayed? -> I guess So. Are all the cells text fields? ->Yes

Comment: What is the problem, no data or scrolling speed?

Comment: Scrolling Speed

Comment: Ask a question about scrolling speed instead of data not populating.

Comment: If you set the identifier of the table column to be the same as the table cell view, does it revert to showing data but slow scrolling?

Comment: @KenThomases : Yes

Comment: OK, so that's one mystery solved: the default behavior, if you don't implement `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` in your delegate (or if you do and just implement it to do the standard behavior), then the table view gets the cell view by using the same identifier as the column. If you set neither identifier, then Xcode makes them match automatically. If you only set one, then they don't match and you don't get any cell views. If you set them both to match, then things work again. The remaining mystery is why scrolling is slow. It may just be due to the number of columns.